# Get Version of exe via PHP

Tags: php

Is getting the version of a exe possible with php? I'd like to print the version of a file that can be downloaded...

Windows exe and php is running on linux server

Comment: What do you mean by the version of an exe?

Comment: Is the PHP script running on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 22):

I wanted the same thing, so I coded this:
It returns FALSE, if it can't get the version info, or an ARRAY of four elements with file version fields (numbers, which are separated by .) It works only for 32-bit PE files (as I had no need for other formats).

```
function GetFileVersion($FileName)
{
    $handle = fopen($FileName, 'rb');
    if(!$handle)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $Header = fread($handle, 64);
    if(substr($Header, 0, 2) != 'MZ')
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $PEOffset = unpack("V", substr($Header, 60, 4));
    if($PEOffset[1] < 64)
    {
        return FALSE;        
    }
    fseek($handle, $PEOffset[1], SEEK_SET);
    $Header = fread($handle, 24);
    if(substr($Header, 0, 2) != 'PE')
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $Machine = unpack("v", substr($Header, 4, 2));
    if($Machine[1] != 332)
    {        
        return FALSE;
    }
    $NoSections = unpack("v", substr($Header, 6, 2));
    $OptHdrSize = unpack("v", substr($Header, 20, 2));
    fseek($handle, $OptHdrSize[1], SEEK_CUR);
    $ResFound = FALSE;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $NoSections[1]; $x++)
    {
        $SecHdr = fread($handle, 40);
        if (substr($SecHdr, 0, 5) == '.rsrc')
        {
            $ResFound = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$ResFound)
    {        
      return FALSE;
    }
    $InfoVirt = unpack("V", substr($SecHdr, 12, 4));
    $InfoSize = unpack("V", substr($SecHdr, 16, 4));
    $InfoOff = unpack("V", substr($SecHdr, 20, 4));
    fseek($handle, $InfoOff[1], SEEK_SET);
    $Info = fread($handle, $InfoSize[1]);
    $NumDirs = unpack("v", substr($Info, 14, 2));
    $InfoFound = FALSE;
    for ($x = 0; $x <$NumDirs[1]; $x++)
    {
        $Type = unpack("V", substr($Info, ($x * 8) + 16, 4));
        if($Type[1] == 16)
        {
            //FILEINFO resource
            $InfoFound = TRUE;
            $SubOff = unpack("V", substr($Info, ($x * 8) + 20, 4));
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$InfoFound)
    {        
        return FALSE;
    }
    $SubOff[1] &= 0x7fffffff;
    $InfoOff = unpack("V", substr($Info, $SubOff[1] + 20, 4)); //offset of first FILEINFO
    $InfoOff[1] &= 0x7fffffff;
    $InfoOff = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1] + 20, 4));    //offset to data
    $DataOff = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1], 4));
    $DataSize = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1] + 4, 4));
    $CodePage = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1] + 8, 4));
    $DataOff[1] -= $InfoVirt[1];
    $Version = unpack("v4", substr($Info, $DataOff[1] + 48, 8));
    $x = $Version[2];
    $Version[2] = $Version[1];
    $Version[1] = $x;
    $x = $Version[4];
    $Version[4] = $Version[3];
    $Version[3] = $x;
    return $Version;
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me without any problem. The code posted by Scott only showed the first 2 version parts. Thank you.

Comment: Just a minor problem: for ($x=0;x<$NoSections[1];$x++) - $ is missing. But works, nice one.

Comment: hi Toni, do you mind if I take this code and stick it in a gist or a github repo for future reference by myself and others?

Comment: Apart from the mistake James pointed out, this script will also fail if there are any "named" resources. Probably the easiest way to fix this is to add `$NumNamedDirs=unpack("v",substr($Info,12,2));` to the extraction of `$NumDirs` and then add these two values together in the loop below.

Comment: I don't believe this works with 64-bit exes. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 14):

I recently moved our hosting from Windows to Linux. This was quite easy to do with VBScript given the Microsoft objects, but on Linux and PHP I couldn't find anything. We wrote this function in PHP to scan the .exe file and extract the "Product Version" that a VB.Net application had in it. You can change the $key to be whatever string you can find that has the version info and a null terminator.

Note that this scans the files in 64k chunks looking for the $key string. If you have a large .exe, it may take a few seconds. My .exe is 52k so it is nearly instant. If you have a larger exe, you can change the scan.

```
<?php

function get_product_version($file_name)
{
   $key = "P\x00r\x00o\x00d\x00u\x00c\x00t\x00V\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00\x00\x00";
   $fptr = fopen($file_name, "rb");
   $data = "";
   while (!feof($fptr))
   {
      $data .= fread($fptr, 65536);
      if (strpos($data, $key)!==FALSE)
         break;
      $data = substr($data, strlen($data)-strlen($key));
   }
   fclose($fptr);
   if (strpos($data, $key)===FALSE)
      return "";
   $pos = strpos($data, $key)+strlen($key);
   $version = "";
   for ($i=$pos; $data[$i]!="\x00"; $i+=2)
      $version .= $data[$i];
   return $version;
}

echo get_product_version("/path_to_file/foo.exe");
?>
```

Comment: thanks, for great with .NET files compiled by visual studio. But finds nothing for MONO assemblies. Looking now whats different in MONO assemblies.

Comment: Works indeed great for .NET files. I also added an check  if (! file_exists($file_name)). Otherwise if the file is not found this results in an infinite-loop.

Comment: This also works with InnoSetup installer files.  Brilliant

Answer (score 11):

On a win32 machine you can use the [COM extension](http://docs.php.net/COM) and [FileSystemObject.GetFileVersion()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4e05k97%28VS.85%29.aspx) method to retrieve the version info.
e.g.

```
$path = getenv('SystemRoot').'\\NOTEPAD.EXE';
$fso = new COM('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
echo $path, ' : ', $fso->GetFileVersion($path);
```

prints (on my machine) `C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE : 5.1.2600.5512`

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you're not on Windows, and you mean the Version information that can be stored in Windows executables, and pops up in the properties dialog for such a file in Windows Explorer.

This information seems to be stored in the `VS_VERSION_INFO` block of an executable (see for example [this question](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t144686-retrieve-version-number-for-windows-executable.html)). I don't know any tool that extracts this information in a simple way, not even on Windows itself.

There seem to be several ways to get hold of this information via the Windows API (See a Perl example [here](http://markmail.org/message/36gv5shtjusa4iih)) but I can't see any approach that works "from scratch" by just parsing the executable.

If you dig around a bit, you might be able to find a file format description that explains how to read the `VS_VERSION_INFO` information from an EXE file. Be prepared for a lot of work to get this to work reliably, though.

Be prepared to invest a lot of time and effort if you want to do this.

Comment: Windows exe and php is running on linux server

Answer (score 4):

I combined the answers together and added the NamedDirs fix. Also want to highlight not to use the code by NeuD, the offset should remain 16; 14 is definitely wrong. Hope it helps someone.

```
function GetFileVersion($FileName)
{
    return GetValueOfSeeking($FileName, "FileVersion");
}

function GetValueOfSeeking($FileName, $seeking)
{
    $handle = fopen($FileName, 'rb');
    if (!$handle) return FALSE;
    $Header = fread($handle, 64);

    if (substr($Header, 0, 2) != 'MZ') return FALSE;

    $PEOffset = unpack("V", substr($Header, 60, 4));
    if ($PEOffset[1]<64) return FALSE;

    fseek($handle, $PEOffset[1], SEEK_SET);
    $Header = fread ($handle, 24);

    if (substr($Header, 0, 2) != 'PE') return FALSE;

    $Machine = unpack("v", substr($Header, 4, 2));
    if ($Machine[1] != 332) return FALSE;

    $NoSections = unpack("v", substr($Header, 6, 2));
    $OptHdrSize = unpack("v", substr($Header, 20, 2));
    fseek($handle, $OptHdrSize[1], SEEK_CUR);

    $ResFound = FALSE;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $NoSections[1]; $x++)
    {
        //$x fixed here
        $SecHdr = fread($handle, 40);
        if (substr($SecHdr, 0, 5) == '.rsrc')
        {
            //resource section
            $ResFound = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$ResFound) return FALSE;
    $InfoVirt = unpack("V", substr($SecHdr, 12, 4));
    $InfoSize = unpack("V", substr($SecHdr, 16, 4));
    $InfoOff = unpack("V", substr($SecHdr, 20, 4));

    fseek($handle, $InfoOff[1], SEEK_SET);
    $Info = fread($handle, $InfoSize[1]);

    $NumNamedDirs = unpack("v",substr($Info, 12, 2));
    $NumDirs = unpack("v", substr($Info, 14, 2));

    $InfoFound = FALSE;
    for ($x = 0; $x < ($NumDirs[1] + $NumNamedDirs[1]); $x++)
    {
        $Type = unpack("V", substr($Info, ($x * 8) + 16, 4));
        if($Type[1] == 16)
        {
            //FILEINFO resource
            $InfoFound = TRUE;
            $SubOff = unpack("V", substr($Info, ($x * 8) + 20, 4));
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$InfoFound) return FALSE;

    if (0)
    {
        $SubOff[1]  &= 0x7fffffff;
        $InfoOff    = unpack("V", substr($Info, $SubOff[1] + 20, 4)); //offset of first FILEINFO
        $InfoOff[1] &= 0x7fffffff;
        $InfoOff    = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1] + 20, 4));    //offset to data
        $DataOff    = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1], 4));
        $DataSize   = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1] + 4, 4));
        $CodePage   = unpack("V", substr($Info, $InfoOff[1] + 8, 4));
        $DataOff[1] -= $InfoVirt[1];
        $Version    = unpack("v4", substr($Info, $DataOff[1] + 48, 8));
        $x          = $Version[2];
        $Version[2] = $Version[1];
        $Version[1] = $x;
        $x          = $Version[4];
        $Version[4] = $Version[3];
        $Version[3] = $x;

        return $Version;
    }

    //view data...
    //echo print_r(explode("\x00\x00\x00", $Info));
    // could prolly substr on VS_VERSION_INFO
    $encodedKey = implode("\x00",str_split($seeking));
    $StartOfSeekingKey = strpos($Info, $encodedKey);
    if ($StartOfSeekingKey !== false) {
        $ulgyRemainderOfData = substr($Info, $StartOfSeekingKey);
        $ArrayOfValues = explode("\x00\x00\x00", $ulgyRemainderOfData);
        // the key your are seeking is 0, where the value is one
        return trim($ArrayOfValues[1]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on the answer Toni provided
One of the projects at work had a custom attribute baked into that resource section. On a linux machine we didnt want to install perl to use the windows function to get the values.
Instead one can use this variant of the GetFileVersion to get any value you are seeking. (FileVersion, ProductVersion, ProductName, CompanyName, CompanyWebsite)
It should return false for values that dont exist, and it functions rather quick.

```
    $handle=fopen($FileName,'rb');
    if (!$handle) return FALSE;
    $Header=fread ($handle,64);
    if (substr($Header,0,2)!='MZ') return FALSE;
    $PEOffset=unpack("V",substr($Header,60,4));
    if ($PEOffset[1]<64) return FALSE;
    fseek($handle,$PEOffset[1],SEEK_SET);
    $Header=fread ($handle,24);
    if (substr($Header,0,2)!='PE') return FALSE;
    $Machine=unpack("v",substr($Header,4,2));
    if ($Machine[1]!=332) return FALSE;
    $NoSections=unpack("v",substr($Header,6,2));
    $OptHdrSize=unpack("v",substr($Header,20,2));
    fseek($handle,$OptHdrSize[1],SEEK_CUR);
    $ResFound=FALSE;
    for ($x=0;$x<$NoSections[1];$x++) {
            $SecHdr=fread($handle,40);
            if (substr($SecHdr,0,5)=='.rsrc') {         //resource section
                    $ResFound=TRUE;
                    break;
            }
    }

    if (!$ResFound) return FALSE;
    $InfoVirt=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,12,4));
    $InfoSize=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,16,4));
    $InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,20,4));
    fseek($handle,$InfoOff[1],SEEK_SET);
    $Info=fread($handle,$InfoSize[1]);
    $NumDirs=unpack("v",substr($Info,14,2));
    $InfoFound=FALSE;
    for ($x=0;$x<$NumDirs[1];$x++) {
            $Type=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+16,4));
            if($Type[1]==16) {                          //FILEINFO resource
                    $InfoFound=TRUE;
                    $SubOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+20,4));
                    //echo $Info;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if (!$InfoFound) return FALSE;

    // i bypassed this, but if you knew the layout you could prolly do a little better then $ulgyRemainderOfData
    /*
    $SubOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
    $InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$SubOff[1]+20,4)); //offset of first FILEINFO
    $InfoOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
    $InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+20,4));    //offset to data
    $DataOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1],4));
    $DataSize=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+4,4));
    $CodePage=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+8,4));
    $DataOff[1]-=$InfoVirt[1];
    $Version=unpack("v4",substr($Info,$DataOff[1]+48,8));

    // swap 1-2 3-4 / endian ecoding issue
    $x=$Version[2];
    $Version[2]=$Version[1];
    $Version[1]=$x;
    $x=$Version[4];
    $Version[4]=$Version[3];
    $Version[3]=$x;
    return $Version;
    */

    //view data...
    //echo print_r(explode("\x00\x00\x00", $Info));
    // could prolly substr on VS_VERSION_INFO
    $encodedKey = implode("\x00",str_split($seeking));
    $StartOfSeekingKey = strpos($Info, $encodedKey);
    if ($StartOfSeekingKey !== false) {
        $ulgyRemainderOfData = substr($Info, $StartOfSeekingKey);

        $ArrayOfValues = explode("\x00\x00\x00", $ulgyRemainderOfData);
        // the key your are seeking is 0, where the value is one
        return trim($ArrayOfValues[1]);
    }

    return false;
}


$fileVersion = GetValueOfSeeking("./the/path/to/some.exe", 'FileVersion');
$myAttribute = GetValueOfSeeking("./the/path/to/some.exe", 'CustomAttribute');
```

Comment: Why on the first for loop the "x" variable is used without "$"? This is generating error/Notices, but the final result is correct (1.0.0.0). However, if I put the "$" before "x", and I assume this is was your typo, the final result becomes wrong (1.0.0.‰)

Comment: That is / was a typo. However the exe that I've been running through that function has no problem with that loop.The x is copied from the answer a few posts down. Perhaps something is different with your exe?

Comment: Well for some reason, the problem is the final trim function. I replaced the trim with str_replace and everything is ok now. Thx!

Comment: This one should suffer from the same problem as I already described in Toni's post. It will fail if there are any named resources, but it's easy enough to fix (see above).

Answer (score 1):

For me to get the code from Toni to work I had to do a small change:

```
function GetFileVersion($FileName) {

$handle=fopen($FileName,'rb');
if (!$handle) return FALSE;
$Header=fread ($handle,64);
if (substr($Header,0,2)!='MZ') return FALSE;
$PEOffset=unpack("V",substr($Header,60,4));
if ($PEOffset[1]<64) return FALSE;
fseek($handle,$PEOffset[1],SEEK_SET);
$Header=fread ($handle,24);
if (substr($Header,0,2)!='PE') return FALSE;
$Machine=unpack("v",substr($Header,4,2));
if ($Machine[1]!=332) return FALSE;
$NoSections=unpack("v",substr($Header,6,2));
$OptHdrSize=unpack("v",substr($Header,20,2));
fseek($handle,$OptHdrSize[1],SEEK_CUR);
$ResFound=FALSE;
for ($x=0;$x<$NoSections[1];$x++) {      //$x fixed here
    $SecHdr=fread($handle,40);
    if (substr($SecHdr,0,5)=='.rsrc') {         //resource section
        $ResFound=TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$ResFound) return FALSE;
$InfoVirt=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,12,4));
$InfoSize=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,16,4));
$InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,20,4));
fseek($handle,$InfoOff[1],SEEK_SET);
$Info=fread($handle,$InfoSize[1]);
$NumDirs=unpack("v",substr($Info,16,2));
$InfoFound=FALSE;
for ($x=0;$x<$NumDirs[1];$x++) {
    $Type=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+16,4));
    if($Type[1]==16) {             //FILEINFO resource
        $InfoFound=TRUE;
        $SubOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+20,4));
        break;
    }
}
if (!$InfoFound) return FALSE;
$SubOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
$InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$SubOff[1]+20,4)); //offset of first FILEINFO
$InfoOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
$InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+20,4));    //offset to data
$DataOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1],4));
$DataSize=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+4,4));
$CodePage=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+8,4));
$DataOff[1]-=$InfoVirt[1];
$Version=unpack("v4",substr($Info,$DataOff[1]+48,8));
$x=$Version[2];
$Version[2]=$Version[1];
$Version[1]=$x;
$x=$Version[4];
$Version[4]=$Version[3];
$Version[3]=$x;
return $Version;
}
```

Where I only changed 14 to 16 in the line

```
$NumDirs=unpack("v",substr($Info,16,2));
```

Maybe this has something to do with what j_schultz already added in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small code that will pull the file version directly from the executable.
**PHP**:

```
<?php

function exeparser_fileversion($file) {
    $parser_model = array('begin'=>"F\x00i\x00l\x00e\x00V\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n",'end'=>"\x00\x00\x00");
    if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
        $version = file_get_contents($file);
        $version = explode($parser_model['begin'], $version);
        $version = explode($parser_model['end'], $version[1]);
        $version = str_replace("\x00", null, $version[1]);
        return ((!empty($version) ? "\x1b[32m$file version: $version\x1b[0m" : "\x1b[31mNo version\x1b[0m"));
    } else {
        print "\x1b[31m".(is_dir($file) ? "Specified path points to a directory, not a file." : "The specified path to the file may not exist or is not a file at all.")."\x1b[0m";
        return false;
    }
}

@print exeparser_fileversion($argv[1]);

?>
```

**Windows command** (optional):

```
@php "%~dp0\exeparser.php" %*
```

## Result:

[image]