# Can I get information from .exe files using PHP

Tags: php, exe

I need to read out information from an .EXE file. Is this possible to do using PHP?

After I uploaded the .EXE file to the server, I want to retrieve: application name, version number & icon. Is there any more information to collect?

Is it possible to do this using PHP?

If not, is there any other way I can get this information?

Comment: Although I don't know your answer, I would say are you sure you want to upload EXE files to your webserver? I think you'd be better to put them all into individual ZIP files or something else, in case of security exploits.

Comment: The problem still exist, i need the info inside the exe file.

Comments about safety is not needed here. I just want to know if it is possible, and if so, how?

Comment: This question has been asked already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029409/get-version-of-exe-via-php

Comment: What kind of info do you need? php has lots of function to open and read files so you can do it. what you need is structure description of the file.

Comment: Yes, you can read the information from an exe file. Each file has some code at the beginning to identify the type of the file and some other information. You can find out more about these information at [wikipedia][1] - magic numbers in files.

Also read [this post][2] which answers similar question


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029409/get-version-of-exe-via-php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Code snippet to extract the icon from an exe file on a Linux system -- tested on Debian Wheezy

// Install icoutils on your system e.g. sudo apt-get install icoutils
// Web process must have write privileges to /tmp

///** Config **///

$input_file = '/path/to/program.exe';
$dest_file = '/path/to/image.png';
$dest_size = 64; // Will get the best quality icon at or below this size.

///** End Config **///


$temp_dir_base = '/tmp/iconextract/';
$tmp_offset = 0;
while(file_exists($temp_dir_base.$tmp_offset.'/')){ //Ensure working directory is empty
    $tmp_offset += 1;
}

$tmp_dir = $temp_dir_base.$tmp_offset.'/';

mkdir($tmp_dir,0777,true);  //Create a temporary folder to work in
exec('wrestool -x '.str_replace(' ','\\',$input_file).' -o '.$tmp_dir); //Extract ico files
$icon_files = glob($tmp_dir.'*.ico'); //Find all ico files

$max = 0;
$file = 0;
$index = 0;
foreach($icon_files as $file_offset=>$ico){ //loop each match
    exec('icotool -l '.$ico.' --icon',$list); //get each icon inside the file
    foreach($list as $i){ //Loop through each icon
        preg_match_all('/--index=(?P<index>\d+) --width=(?P<width>\d+) --height=(?P<height>\d+)/',$i,$a);
        if($a['width'][0] > $max and $a['width'][0] <= $dest_size){
            $max = $a['width'][0];
            $index = $a['index'][0];
            $file = $file_offset;
        }
    }
}

if($max > 0){ //If we found one, extract it to the destination
    exec('icotool -x '.$icon_files[$file].' -i '.$index.' -o '.str_replace(' ','\\',$dest_file));
}
else{
    exec('rm '.$tmp_dir.' -r'); //Clean out tmp files
    $error = "Could not find a sutiable icon file";
    throw new Exception($error);
}
exec('rm /tmp/iconextract -r'); //Clean out tmp files

?>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/mrkmg/4568896

He is using a utillity called icoutils to get the icon and uses php to call the utillity

And this:

```
function GetFileVersion($FileName) {

$handle=fopen($FileName,'rb');
if (!$handle) return FALSE;
$Header=fread ($handle,64);
if (substr($Header,0,2)!='MZ') return FALSE;
$PEOffset=unpack("V",substr($Header,60,4));
if ($PEOffset[1]<64) return FALSE;
fseek($handle,$PEOffset[1],SEEK_SET);
$Header=fread ($handle,24);
if (substr($Header,0,2)!='PE') return FALSE;
$Machine=unpack("v",substr($Header,4,2));
if ($Machine[1]!=332) return FALSE;
$NoSections=unpack("v",substr($Header,6,2));
$OptHdrSize=unpack("v",substr($Header,20,2));
fseek($handle,$OptHdrSize[1],SEEK_CUR);
$ResFound=FALSE;
for ($x=0;x<$NoSections[1];$x++) {
    $SecHdr=fread($handle,40);
    if (substr($SecHdr,0,5)=='.rsrc') {         //resource section
        $ResFound=TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$ResFound) return FALSE;
$InfoVirt=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,12,4));
$InfoSize=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,16,4));
$InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,20,4));
fseek($handle,$InfoOff[1],SEEK_SET);
$Info=fread($handle,$InfoSize[1]);
$NumDirs=unpack("v",substr($Info,14,2));
$InfoFound=FALSE;
for ($x=0;$x<$NumDirs[1];$x++) {
    $Type=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+16,4));
    if($Type[1]==16) {                          //FILEINFO resource
        $InfoFound=TRUE;
        $SubOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+20,4));
        break;
    }
}
if (!$InfoFound) return FALSE;
$SubOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
$InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$SubOff[1]+20,4)); //offset of first FILEINFO
$InfoOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
$InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+20,4));    //offset to data
$DataOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1],4));
$DataSize=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+4,4));
$CodePage=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+8,4));
$DataOff[1]-=$InfoVirt[1];
$Version=unpack("v4",substr($Info,$DataOff[1]+48,8));
$x=$Version[2];
$Version[2]=$Version[1];
$Version[1]=$x;
$x=$Version[4];
$Version[4]=$Version[3];
$Version[3]=$x;
return $Version;
}
```

source: [Get Version of exe via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029409/get-version-of-exe-via-php)